# Code freezes my application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, screenshot

This code extremly freezes the WPF application.

Is there ANY chance to fix it?

```
var getScreenshot = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{                       
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new ThreadStart(() => {                        
    #region Main
    try
    {
        Graphics gfx;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        WindowInteropHelper windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        Screen screen = Screen.FromHandle(windowInteropHelper.Handle);
        gfx.CopyFromScreen(screen.Bounds.X, screen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, screen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] bitmapData = null;
        using (bmp)
        {
            bmp.SetResolution(72, 72);
            ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
            myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder;
            myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
            EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters();
            EncoderParameter encoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 25L);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = encoderParameter;
            bmp.Save(ms, myImageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);                               
            bitmapData = ms.ToArray();
        }
        if (bitmapData != null)
            DataProvider.UpdateScreen(((PlayerConfiguration)App.Current.Properties["PlayerConfig"]).InstallationKey, bitmapData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        #region Error
        LogEntry l = new LogEntry();
        l.Message = string.Format("{0}", ex.Message);
        l.Title = "GetScreen() Error";
        l.Categories.Add(Category.General);
        l.Priority = Priority.Highest;

        CustomLogger.WriteErrorLog(l, "GetScreen");

        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
  }));

}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
.ContinueWith(x => x.Dispose());
```

Comment: extremely freezes? Is that warmer or colder than 'totally freezes'?

Comment: @MarcB: funny :), but be polite

Comment: @MarcB It is colder man, very colder. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just don't dispatch to the UI thread for the whole thing.  Only put the smallest amount of code into the `Invoke` call that you can get away with.  It should be when you're actually updating the UI.  Since the whole thing is in the invoke call in your code, the UI is blocked until the whole thing finishes.

Comment: Please tell me which part of the code I have to put into Invoke? Could u guess please?

Comment: @Peretz Looking over your code none of it seems to be interacting with controls that I can see, so you shouldn't be moving into the UI thread at all.  If you get an error for accessing a control in the wrong thread, then it'll tell you exactly which line needs to be wrapped in an `Invoke` call.

Comment: I put those lines within an INVOKE ----->  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new ThreadStart(() => {    
                                
                                    WindowInteropHelper windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
                                    screen = Screen.FromHandle(windowInteropHelper.Handle);
                                    gfx.CopyFromScreen(screen.Bounds.X, screen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, screen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
 }));   -----------|  But it doesn't help :(

Comment: How does MS Windows does screenshot and nothing is freezing?

Comment: @Peretz The whole point is that you should **not** be using the `Dispatcher.Invoke`, not that you should be.

Comment: @Peretz Taking a screenshot is quite fast, it's the saving the file that's slow, and you don't need to block the UI while that's going on.